# Using PowerShell to monitor log files - parsing data

Tags: windows, powershell

I am a novice at both scripting and PowerShell.

I've managed to set up a script that checks server log files and then sends me an email with a list of lines that show a failure to login by a user in the log. The log files contain rows of data that have this info in each line:

```
date&time        Login.Success(or Login.Failure)        IP        Username
```

Is there a way when checking the day's log file that I can parse the data so that rather than sending me an email with every user who had a login.failure, it could compare every line in the file to see if that user also had a login.success and remove those users from the final list (so that ultimately I only get a list of events where the user did not eventually manage to login)?

Right now I am getting a list of users who had login failures but I can only tell that they tried to login unsuccessfully 5 times in a row, but not if they then managed to login successfully on the 6th try. I want a list of users who had unsuccessful logins only.

Comment: is the data in your log file separated by spaces or tabs? can you put the first 10 rows in a pastebin link so we can see the data you are working with?

Comment: It is separated by tabs. Here is a link to some sample data: http://pastebin.com/ruj681iW

Comment: are you able to use this? ``import-csv c:\temp\yourfilehere.txt -delim "`t"``

Comment: Yes, that gives me a sorted list. What do I need to do next to get it to filter  Login.Failure events only for usernames that are not also connected to a Login.Success or Logout event? Thank you - I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: would you be able to send a screenshot of your sorted list?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the first part of the list: http://imgur.com/0jDSF28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have your data in an object then you could group on username where there is no success

contents of c:\temp\file.log

```
2016-06-02T15:06:59 Login.Success   127.0.0.1   user1
2016-06-02T15:06:59 Login.Failure   127.0.0.1   user1
2016-06-02T15:06:59 Login.Success   127.0.0.1   user2
2016-06-02T15:06:59 Login.Failure   127.0.0.1   user3
```

sample script

```
$a = ipcsv c:\temp\file.log -delim "`t" -header date, login, ip, username

$a | group username | ? {($_.group.login | Out-String) -NotMatch 'success|logout'}
```

*edit: after seeing your comments and your screenshot, try this

```
$results = ipcsv c:\temp\file.log -delim "`t" | group username | ? {($_.group.login | Out-String) -NotMatch 'success|logout'} | % {$_.group | sort {date $_.'date/time'} -Descending | select -f 1} | % {$_ | fl * | out-string}
```

then use `$results` as the -body in your email

Comment: I neglected to note that it also logs "Logout" as an option, so even if they aren't matched to "Success" they might be a "Logout" instead of a "Failure." Can you use -NotMatch with two parameters?

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work so far. Currently it is just returning a full list of everything (success, failure, logout) from the text file.

Comment: try removing the `-header ...` part and everything after it on that line

Comment: Thank you, that works. Although, I'm having trouble converting the resulting data into string data that can be passed through email. Right now my email body is coming through only as "System.Collections.Hashtable" rather than the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

I created some sample data and saved it to a text file:

```
date&time        Login.Failure        192.168.2.1        Asterix
date&time        Login.Failure        192.168.2.1        Asterix
date&time        Login.Failure        192.168.2.2        Oberlix
date&time        Login.Failure        192.168.2.3        Siegfried
date&time        Login.Failure        192.168.2.3        Siegfried
date&time        Login.Success        192.168.2.3        Siegfried
date&time        Login.Failure        192.168.2.4        Siegfried
date&time        Login.Failure        192.168.2.4        Michael
date&time        Login.Failure        192.168.2.5        Michael
```

To parse them, I read the file using the Get-Content cmdlet and create a `PSCustomObject` foreach line:

```
$parsedResult = Get-Content 'your_log_file.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    $record = $_ -split '\s{2,}'
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        DateTime = $record[0]
        Login = $record[1]
        IP = $record[2]
        Username = $record[3]
    }    
}
```

Now I have an array of objects (`$parsedResult`) that I can use to filter. If I just print it, it looks like:

```
DateTime  Login         IP          Username 
--------  -----         --          -------- 
date&time Login.Failure 192.168.2.1 Asterix  
date&time Login.Failure 192.168.2.1 Asterix  
date&time Login.Failure 192.168.2.2 Oberlix  
date&time Login.Failure 192.168.2.3 Siegfried
date&time Login.Failure 192.168.2.3 Siegfried
date&time Login.Success 192.168.2.3 Siegfried
date&time Login.Failure 192.168.2.4 Siegfried
date&time Login.Failure 192.168.2.4 Michael  
date&time Login.Failure 192.168.2.5 Michael
```

To filter all user that have a successfull login, I created a list:

```
$userToExclude =  @($parsedResult | Where-Object Login -eq 'Login.Success' | select -expand UserName)
```

In this example it only contains `Siegfried`

Now exclude all user within the list:

```
$parsedResult | Where-Object Username -NotIn $userToExclude
```

Output:

```
DateTime  Login         IP          Username
--------  -----         --          --------
date&time Login.Failure 192.168.2.1 Asterix 
date&time Login.Failure 192.168.2.1 Asterix 
date&time Login.Failure 192.168.2.2 Oberlix 
date&time Login.Failure 192.168.2.4 Michael 
date&time Login.Failure 192.168.2.5 Michael
```

You could also group this:

```
$parsedResult | Where-Object Username -NotIn $userToExclude | Group-Object Username -NoElement
```

And get something like this:

```
Count Name                     
----- ----                     
    2 Asterix                  
    1 Oberlix                  
    2 Michael
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this is very helpful. I'll try this and see how it goes.

Comment: I am running into this error when I get to the second part ($userToExclude):

Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert the "Event" value of type "System.String" to
System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
At line:1 char:49
+ $userToExclude =  @($parsedResult | Where-Object <<<<  Event -eq 'Login.Success' | select -expand Username)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand